# How can I remove the red border around hyperref TextField?

Tags: formatting, hyperref, forms

I'm creating a form using `hyperref`'s `Form` environment. All the fields are included in a table, so I want to hide the red borders around them, as they are already evident. I tried with the `hidelinks` option,but it doesn't work. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Name & \TextField[width=5cm]{}\\
\hline
Surname & \TextField[width=5cm]{}\\
\hline
City & \TextField[width=5cm]{}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

produces this form:

[image: example of wrong output (with red borders)]

where I expected (and wanted) this other one, still fillable:

[image: example of desired output (without red borders)]

How can I achieve that?

**Note:** what I'm trying to do is to *completely hide* `\TextField` borders while keeping the fillable field, surroundend by the table cell borders.

Comment: How should a potential reader of your document find out that the empty fells are in fact fillable?

Comment: I'll specify that in the compilation instructions. The real one will be much more complicate than my MWE, so I'd have to provide them anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Name & \TextField[bordercolor={},backgroundcolor={},width=5cm]{}\\
\hline
Surname & \TextField[bordercolor={},backgroundcolor={},width=5cm]{}\\
\hline
City & \TextField[bordercolor={},backgroundcolor={},width=5cm]{}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose this variant layout with `booktabs` and an `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{Sl!{\color{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\vrule width4pt} l}
Name & \TextField[width=5cm, borderwidth=0]{}\\
\midrule
Surname & \TextField[width=5cm,borderwidth=0]{}\\
\midrule
City & \TextField[width=5cm, borderwidth=0]{}
\end{tabular}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution kind of improves the form, but I woud like to completely remove the borders or at least to make the completely invisible.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood you requirement…

Comment: I added a note to try to make it clearer.